# Adding Adomd parameters programmatically C#

Tags: c#, mdx, adomd.net

Afternoon all.

I'm building a web app and I'm attempting to pull through some data from an SSAS cube.

I have the following MDX I would like to replicate in c# but with adding a few parameters i.e. two parameteres, one for company 123 and another for location 1:

```
@"SELECT NON EMPTY([Dim Unit].[All Units].[Category Group Name]) ON COLUMNS
                    FROM [Info]
                    WHERE ([Dim Company].[All Companies].&[123], 
                    [Dim Location].[All Locations].&[123]&[1])";
```

Now, I can get this up and running with one parameter:

```
 AdomdCommand cmdPDC = conPDC.CreateCommand();
        cmdPDC.CommandText = "SELECT [Dim Unit].[All Units].[Category Group Name].Members ON 0 FROM [Info] WHERE (StrToMember(@P1)";

        string companyid = "123";

        string sP1 = "[Dim Company].&" + company;

    cmdPDC.Parameters.Add(new AdomdParameter("P1", sP1));
```

But how do I then implement a second parameter, for example, if I wanted to stick a parameter in for location? I was thinking along the lines ofbelow but I can't get the little sod to work:

```
AdomdCommand cmdPDC = conPDC.CreateCommand();
        cmdPDC.CommandText = "SELECT [Dim Unit].[All Units].[Category Group Name].Members ON 0 FROM [Info] WHERE (StrToMember(@P1)," + "(StrToMember(@P2))";

        string companyid = "123";
        string locationid = "1";

        string sP1 = "[Dim Company].&" + company;
        string sP2 = "[Dim Location].&" + company + "&" + location;

        cmdPDC.Parameters.Add(new AdomdParameter("P1", sP1));
        cmdPDC.Parameters.Add(new AdomdParameter("P2", sP2));
```

Any help or advice gratefully received.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A solution!

```
AdomdCommand cmdPDC = conPDC.CreateCommand();
cmdPDC.CommandText = "SELECT NON EMPTY [Dim Unit].[All Units].[Category Name].Members ON 0 FROM [MY CUBE] WHERE (StrToMember(@CompanyId),StrToMember(@LocationId))";

string companyid = "[123]";
string locationid = "[1]";

string sCompanyId = "[Dim Company].&" + companyid;
string sLocationId = "[Dim Location].&" + companyid + "&" + locationid;

cmdPDC.Parameters.Add(new AdomdParameter("CompanyId", sCompanyId));
cmdPDC.Parameters.Add(new AdomdParameter("LocationId", sLocationId));
```

And a few little pointers.

You may receive this error:

"X parameter could not be resolved because it was referenced in an inner subexpression"

Resolution: When inserting the `@CompanyId` in the quoted string, make sure the parameter is not enclosed in apostrophes (') - c# is clever and will convert the data type and add these apostrophes in for you. However, you won't be able to see it in a watch window and all would appear to be fine.

All items are returned and it would appear that your parameters are being ignored.

Resolution: Check the very first `SELECT` and make sure it is `SELECT NON EMPTY`.

Comment: can we use parameter name like @[DepartmentMaster].[DepartmentMaster].&[1] ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { 
[Measures].[Phone Count], 
[Measures].[Mail Count], 
[Measures].[Individual Count] 
} ON COLUMNS 
FROM [PyramidReports-US] 
WHERE ( 
 (STRTOSET(@PoliticalGeographyByCD), 
 [Political Geography].[By CD].[State].currentmember ), 
 (STRTOSET(@GenderGender), 
 [Gender].[Gender].currentmember ), 
 (STRTOSET(@ModelAffinityAffinityQuartile), 
 [Model Affinity].[Affinity Quartile].currentmember 
  )
```

How about for a query like this that uses currentmember to populate the parameters?