# Ignore single quote in C#

Tags: c#

In my program I have this statment 
......

```
ct = String.Format(@"select [Movie Selector] from WSTMDS3
            natural prediction join 
            (select

             '{0}'as[Age],
            '{1}'as[Education Level],
            '{2}'as[Gender],
            '{3}'as[Home Ownership],
            '{4}'as[Internet Connection],
            '{5}'as[Marital Status]

            )as MovieSelector",
             TextBox1.Text,
             DropDownList1.SelectedValue,
             DropDownList2.SelectedValue,
             DropDownList3.SelectedValue,
             DropDownList4.SelectedValue,
             DropDownList5.SelectedValue)
                ;
```

But in DropDown list1 "Education Level " 
I have some value like this Master' Degree
how i can use the single quote ' in this statment .

thanks

Comment: I think you would like to build a sql-statement. Try SQL-Parameters

Comment: Analysis Servece
Adomdconnection ........

Comment: I think you should clarify your question if user1208484's answer is not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 10):

You should not use `string.Format` to build your queries. You should use parameterized queries.

```
adomdCommand.CommandText = "SELECT ... @P1 ...";
adomdCommand.Parameters.Add(new AdomdParameter("P1", TextBox1.Text));
// etc..
```

**Related**

- [How do parameterized queries help against SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468425/how-do-parameterized-queries-help-against-sql-injection)
- [Adding Adomd parameters programmatically C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959768/adding-adomd-parameters-programmatically-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

Use SqlCommand and SqlParameter.
Example

```
SqlCommand sqlCom=new SqlCommand();
sqlCom.CommandText=@"select [Movie Selector] from WSTMDS3
        natural prediction join 
        (select

         @P0 as[Age],
        @P1 as[Education Level],
        @P2 as[Gender],
        @P3 as[Home Ownership],
        @P4 as[Internet Connection],
        @P5 as[Marital Status]

        ";
sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P0",TextBox1.Text);
```

Comment: No problem with DMX statment just in qute i need to ignore the qute

Answer (score 0):

Besides using parametrized queries - the escape method for single quotes in T-SQL syntax is to double them.